# Command-line sort and copy text files to one single file renders an error

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I stumbled on question 217394 which explains how to copy files sorted alphabetically into one single file. Trying to implement the command myself rendered the following error message:
The system cannot find the file specified.

The command I am trying to run is here:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /a-d /o-n /b O:\OrdersExport\Order*.txt') do @type %i >> C:\Users\Admin\Documents\OrderImport.txt
```

The error does not appear if I browsed to the folder in question first:

```
C:\>O:
C:\>cd OrdersImport
```

I simply want one line to copy from destination to that single file.

By the way, if it matters, O: is a mapped folder over network

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` command list the filenames only. So `%i` variable is filled with relative paths. If the command is not run from the directory in question use `%~fi` to expand the relative path to absolute path.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /a-d /o-n /b "O:\OrdersExport\Order*.txt"') do (
    @type "%~fi" >> "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\OrderImport.txt"
)
```

- `tokens=*` deals with spaces in filenames, so `%i` is always whole line of the `dir` output.